# How to add animated svg noise background in place of red background

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to add this animated svg noise background here in place of the red background in my code that is below this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/cqh5gsm8/

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  height: calc(100% + 50px);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#111, #111 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  filter: url(#noise);
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
    <section></section>
    <svg>
      <filter id="noise">
        <feTurbulence id="turbulence">
          <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="8s" values="0.9 0.9;0.8 0.8; 0.9 0.9" ></animate>
        </feTurbulence>
        <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="60"></feDisplacementMap>
      </filter>
    </svg>
```

The code I want to add the animated svg noise background to is this one.

I want to replace the red background here, with the animated svg noise background.

How would that be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/yo43h8u5/

[image]

```js
(function (d) {
  const tv = d.querySelector(".curtain");
  tv.addEventListener("click", screenOff);
  function screenOff() {
    tv.classList.toggle("off");
  }

})(document);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;*/
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  /* background: #0a0a0a;*/

}

.ratio-keeper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 41%;
  height: 72%;
  border: 325px solid #0a0a0a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" ><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  clip-path: circle(25% at center);
  animation: fade 8s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;

  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 0.55%;
  /*height: 2px;*/
  background: green;

}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 60%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 70%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 80%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 90%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  animation: fan-spin 100s linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;


}

.cross::before {
  /*horizontal*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 10px;*/
  height: 2.8%;
  clip-path: circle(29% at center);
}

.cross::after
  {/*vertical*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 10px;*/
  width: 1.5%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  clip-path: circle(51% at center);
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}

.off .inner {
  animation: shutdown  210ms 0ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes  shutdown{
  68% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  99% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="curtain ">

    <div class="ratio-keeper">

      <div class="fence">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <div class="fan">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
          <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000" d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" />
        </svg>

      </div>
      <div class="cross"></div>

      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Click to turn OFF</h1> </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add the filter, that recreates static, to your SVG.

```
      <div class="fan">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
          <defs>
            <filter id="noise">
              <feTurbulence id="turbulence">
                <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="8s" values="0.9 0.9;0.8 0.8; 0.9 0.9" ></animate>
              </feTurbulence>
              <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="60"></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
          </defs>
          ...etc...
```

Next, we need to add a new `<div>` to your HTML that will contain the static.  We can't just apply that filter to `<div class="inner">`. Because it'll also affect the text that's in that div.

```
<div class="inner">
  <div class="static"></div>
  <h1>Click to turn OFF</h1>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for that new div.

```
.static {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#111, #111 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  filter: url(#noise);
}
```

Finally we remove the red background from `<div class="inner">`. It's no longer necessary.  And tweak the style a bit more to solve some other minor issues.

```
.inner {
  ...snip...
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner H1 {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**Final result***

```js
(function (d) {
  const tv = d.querySelector(".curtain");
  tv.addEventListener("click", screenOff);
  function screenOff() {
    tv.classList.toggle("off");
  }

})(document);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;*/
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  /* background: #0a0a0a;*/

}

.ratio-keeper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 41%;
  height: 72%;
  border: 325px solid #0a0a0a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" ><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  clip-path: circle(25% at center);
  animation: fade 8s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;

  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 0.55%;
  /*height: 2px;*/
  background: green;

}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 60%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 70%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 80%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 90%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  animation: fan-spin 100s linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;


}

.cross::before {
  /*horizontal*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 10px;*/
  height: 2.8%;
  clip-path: circle(29% at center);
}

.cross::after
  {/*vertical*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 10px;*/
  width: 1.5%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  clip-path: circle(51% at center);
}

.static {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#111, #111 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  filter: url(#noise);
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner H1 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.off .inner {
  animation: shutdown  210ms 0ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes  shutdown{
  68% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  99% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="curtain ">

    <div class="ratio-keeper">

      <div class="fence">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <div class="fan">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
          <defs>
            <filter id="noise">
              <feTurbulence id="turbulence">
                <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="8s" values="0.9 0.9;0.8 0.8; 0.9 0.9" ></animate>
              </feTurbulence>
              <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="60"></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
          </defs>
          <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000" d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" />
        </svg>

      </div>
      <div class="cross"></div>

      <div class="inner">
        <div class="static"></div>
        <h1>Click to turn OFF</h1>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

To replace the background image, you could put something like
this in your .css

```
background: url("url");
```